# Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page. UI Form magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, xml, sql

[I`m using this plugin](https://git.pablomalo.fr/polo/jeff-contacts/-/tree/master) , but i have another table structure.
I can add new item to database bur if i edit item i get err Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.

My table structure id, post , comment, product, status.

i edit **`contacts_test_listing.xml`**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <!-- Here we declare the data_source to use with the tag 'js_config', which makes the links between your grid and the database -->
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">contacts_test_listing.contacts_test_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">contacts_test_listing.contacts_test_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>

        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">contacts_test_columns</item>

        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add a new Contact</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/newAction</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <!-- dataProvider, with a class tag to define the name of the object to be used. -->
    <dataSource name="contacts_contact_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">

            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">ContactsGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">contacts_test_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render" />
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <!-- define the columns of grid: name from spinner -->
    <columns name="contacts_test_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <!-- bookmark behavior -->
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">contacts_test_listing.contacts_test_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">contacts_test_listing.contacts_test_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <!-- ${ $.index } means the current column index -->
                        <!-- ${ $.storageConfig.root }: It is referring to root property of current storageConfig
                            that you previously defined as ${ $.index }.so, at the end it should take the same value as ${ $.index} -->
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <!-- Column ID -->
        <column name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <!-- Column name -->
        <column name="question">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">question</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Question</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <!-- Column email -->
        <column name="answer">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">email</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Answer</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="product_sku">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">comment</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SKU</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">comment</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <!-- action columns edit and delete -->
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Jeff\Contacts\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ContactsActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>

</listing>
```

How set up this plugin for another table name and table structure?

Answer (score 0):

Open the console tab in your browser's developer tools and check if a CORS error has occurred. If there is a CORS error, please add the address to the csp white list... This is the most frequent cause in my case.